# why am I getting SettingWithCopyWarning from pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I went through some questions regarding this warning, and am still a little bit confused. My method looks as follows:

```python
    def _apply_standard_filters(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        logger.info("Applying standard filters")
        df["Type"] = df["Type"].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())

        df = df[df.Type == "xxxx"]

        df = df[df['Other Column'].str.contains(r"some_regex", na=False, regex=True)]

        return df
```

I'm getting warning regarding that line with lambda function. Initially I got the warning when line looked like this:

```python
        df["Type"] = df["Type"].str.strip()
        df["Type"] = df["Type"].str.lower()
```

I thought maybe this is something with assigning twice the same column, so I rewrote to use apply (like in 1st snippet). Still getting the same warning. Finally I rewrote again with loc, like this:

```python
df["Type"] = df.loc[:, "Type"].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())
```

and warning is still there. What am I missing here?

Also here is the output I'm getting

```
2020-08-12 15:38:14,498 - filters - INFO - Applying standard filters
filters.py:16: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["Type"] = df.loc[:, "Type"].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())
```

Perhaps it is regarding something I do bfore that method is called? I'm using this _apply_standard_filters() always, after I use other filtering method depending on user's choice. However, I never touch Type or Other Column before standard filters. usually it looks like this:

```python
df = df[df.Column1.str.contains(r"some other regex pattern", na=False, regex=True)]
df = self._apply_standard_filters(df=df)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Cheers!

**EDIT**

After @r.ook answer I applied his solution, just fixed it a little bit and still have the same warning in front of my face. Now code looks like below:

```python
def _apply_standard_filters(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    logger.info("Applying standard filters")
    df["Type"] = df.loc[:, "Type"].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())

    df = df.loc[df.Type == "xxxx"]

    df = df.loc[df['Other Column'].str.contains(r"some_regex", na=False, regex=True)]

    df = df[df['Other Column'].str.contains(r"some_regex", na=False, regex=True)]

    return df

def filter_something(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = df.loc[df.Column1.str.contains(r"^Some regex", na=False, regex=True)]
    df = self._apply_standard_filters(df=df)
    return df
```

When I run this I'm still getting:

```
filters.py:17: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["Type"] = df.loc[:, "Type"].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())
```

Should I focus on this particular line mentioned in the warning? I haven't seen this warning before. It appeared when I added `strip()` and `lower()` to the `df["Type"]`. When I run the code w/o that line there is no warning, regardless of changes I made in other df assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have lines that look like this `df = df[...]` it will trigger the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

From the last of your question, it seems you are already passing a copy into the method, that's why the warning is triggered.

Do this instead:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.Column1.str.contains(r"some other regex pattern", na=False, regex=True)]
df = self._apply_standard_filters(df=df)
```

Likewise, edit all the lines in your method that follows the same `df = df[...]` pattern:

```
    df = df.loc[:, df.Type == "xxxx"]
    df = df.loc[:, df['Other Column'].str.contains(r"some_regex", na=False, regex=True)]
```

Comment: It's impossible to break lines in comments, so :) Above won't work, it will generate Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
It should look more like df.loc[ df.Type == "vuln" ]

However, I haven't faced the original warning before in this script. And I always used df = df[...] pattern

Comment: What I meant is that when you have `df = df[...]` pattern is that it won't *immediately* trigger the warning, but that any subsequent assignment/changes to `df` *will* trigger the warning.

Comment: I got rid of this pattern `df = df[...]` still getting warning when this exists `df["Type"] = df.loc[:, "Type"].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())`. If I remove that line, there is no warning, even if I get back to `df = df[...]` pattern in other lines